# Connecting to FTP with windows shell doesnt work

Tags: shell, ftp

Connecting with a FTP Server with the shell ftp program should be one of the most simple tasks:

ftp (IP of the server)

If I try to connect I just get no feedback and it doesn't connect. I can connect with other ftp programs but not with the shell. What could be the problem? I can connect with other FTP servers but not with mine over the shell. To connect to my ftp server with other programs like filezilla is no problem.

By shell I mean the windows 7 cmd.exe shell.

Normally I also should be asked for username and password. But the reaction of the shell is just a new line with "ftp>" and it is not connected.

Comment: Are you using powershell or cmd.exe?

Comment: You should be using powershell. It is WAY better than using the cmd.exe shell.

Comment: I tried. Same result

Comment: Here's another link https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/9ef3f3c8-43f5-4022-b557-152b766f1800/using-ftp-in-a-powershell-script?forum=ITCG

Comment: The Links have other topics.

Comment: What about using a command line ftp utility like pscp.exe

Comment: Can you include FileZilla log? But only after you move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: It works fine with FileZilla and with Windows network volume. I also can connect to other ftp servers with the cmd.exe and the order "ftp IP" (IP Address). But if I want to connect to my ftp server with "ftp IP" (my FTP IP) it just goes one line further without doing anything or giving a response.

Comment: I think the problem is that the server wants a passiv ftp client but by default the user in windows cmd.exe is in active mode